# How to change apt settings to display "All packages are up to date." message?

Tags: apt, updates

I have a handful of Ubuntu servers that I SSH into. On some of them when I run "apt update" I receive the message "All packages are up to date." or a message telling me I have some packages I can upgrade. Yet on two of them after running the same command it doesn't show up. Is there a way to change the settings of apt to have it showing that message? Thank you for your response in advance.

Comment: Are you using sudo to enable access?

Comment: Either using sudo, or doing sudo su and running it as root. Doesn't matter. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is ever experiencing such an issue, try deleting PPAs you might be using because they might be causing those issues. After I deleted one PPA on two of the servers, it started showing the messages correctly.